# Apply machine learning to predict discharging and risk of readmission based on medical data

Tags: machine-learning, classification, clustering, dataset

I am new to machine learning. I have a problem where I have to predict patients to be/not to be discharged using hospital data and depending on that prediction (i.e. if the patient is successfully discharged), I have to predict the risk of those patients being readmitted. I have created the feature set but the target class is missing from original dataset. I have provided a snapshot of the feature set. How to apply machine learning solution to this problem as one output will be used in the prediction of another output?[image: data-snapshot] Please help.

Comment: You want to predict, to start, some aspect of Discharge without any data for that variable?

Comment: You need the target labels, o/w you could just cluster the patients and reason on the groups yourself.

Comment: @gunes could I generate the target labels based on human insight. E.g. if temparature, blood pressure, etc is normal I can say discharge so put a 0 against it using simple if else. And later seperate the test data from training which would not contain the labels? That will be a classification but after that how to model the risk of readmission? Thanks in advance

Comment: @rolando2 yes. Target label is missing. Thanks

Comment: "*Target label is missing.*" <<  Not a classification task then. As gunes says, you might be able to cluster the data but then again, if you have the "human insight" why don't just use that directly to label (i.e. classify) new data?

Answer (score 1):

If you do the discharge decision based on human insights, you can add a column for the decision which is filled using an apply function which evaluates a hard-coded decision function.

```py
import pandas as pd
patients = pd.DataFrame(...)

def categorize_discharge_patients(row):
  if row['max_temperature'] > 38: # or some other criterion
    return False
  else:
    return True

patients['discharge'] = patients.apply(categorize_discharge_patients, axis=1)
```

From this data frame, you can separate the discharged patients as follows

```py
patients_discharge = patients.loc[patients['discharge']]
```

However, as @gunes already stated you can than cluster than your data, but the cluster do not necessarily differentiate between readmission or not, but they can find any relation in the data which allows a clustering, so you probably need more information for predicting the readmission. ([Supervised learning on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supervised_learning))

Comment: Thank you. Actually this problem of data labeling is a big one and I came upon some topics on Active Learning to tackle this issue. So 'expert human' labelled data is used to train machine learning models which would in turn create auto labels (through some process of active learning). Amazon has created a framework called SageMaker for this specific task. Happy to know about it. I will create the labels for the training data based on the insights I have and will try to test the data w/o the labels. Then move to unsupervised learning as in a few days as I will be working on bigger datasets.